# How do I disable indexing in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I am trying to use PhpStorm's remote development to work on a project on a remote server. The issue I am having is that when PhpStorm starts up, it wants to run its index, which consumes so much of the server's resources for so long, that it will usually end up crashing the server before it gets a chance to complete. meaning the whole thing needs to start over again, which then crashes the server, and so on.

The few times it manages to get past indexing, everything else runs fine. It's really the indexing that is the issue.

The issue I am having as well is none of the recommendations for stopping or limiting the index work at all.

I have disabled "System Settings -> Synchronize files on frame or editor tab activation" and marked my `node_module`s and `vendor` directories as excluded, but neither of those stop indexing, or prevent indexing of those directories. I have also disabled a ton of plugins, leaving only the bare minimum, but that didn't help either.

Everyone else at the office uses VS Code which doesn't index anything so it uses very few resources, and because of this, won't upgrade the server for me. I also can't pull any of the projects onto my own computer to work on them there, so that isn't an option either. I also want to avoid switching to VS Code as my IDE is already setup, on top of the fact that I am also the only one who uses a debugger, because setting it up on VS Code is a huge hassle.

At this point though, I don't know what else to do. Not a single method for stopping or reducing indexing works at all and I can't work unless the indexer is either disabled or extremely limited.

Comment: I  would suggest we can't help you much without seeing the exact server and filesystem details. I would suggest you [**submit a help request directly with PhpStorm's developer JetBrains**](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731) and they will give you an ability to submit to them all the tracer and log files the PhpStorm uses and this can diagnose exactly why the indexing is timing out.

Comment: I think you only excluded the directories locally (Project -> right-click on directory -> Mark directory as -> Excluded).
But the remote deployment has a different way to it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment.html#exclude-after-creation